# Error on setting a JOB alert

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Yesterday I was searching for a job so that I can set a job alert according to my requirement, when I clicked search on Job Search page, it redirected me to another page and showed the following page.

[image]

I thought it would be better to share this page so the developers or mods of this site can sort this issue out.
Regards!

Comment: Can you give browser version details and an indication of any plugins you might be using? That response gets loaded via AJAX, it shouldn't cause a full page refresh.

Comment: There are no plugins installed on my browser, I'm using chrome Version 61.0.3163.91.

Comment: This is jQuery, isn't it ?

Comment: @TGrif Yes it is.